# Android getting html response instead of json response | Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json

Hi I am having a hard time figuring out what could be the cause of this error. until I tried to use the debug and found out that instead of a json response I am getting an html response. Please help me figure this out.

Check this java code :

from this point the error is triggered

```
StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            AppConfig.URL_SUBMIT_CLIENT, response -> {
                Log.d(TAG, "Submission Response: " + response);
                hideDialog();

                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    Log.d("Debug", jObj.toString());
                    boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("success");
                    if (!error) {

                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Client successfully submitted.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    } else {

                        // Error occurred in registration. Get the error
                        // message
                        String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                                errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
```

and also this is my hp script. I have it also test in some websites and found no error so I'm pretty sure that there is no problem here. I will still post it and leave it to you guys and If there is a problem please point it out.

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/DB_Connect.php';

$db = new DB_CONNECT();

$query = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO clientinformation(amountApplied, mop, term, lastname, firstname, middlename, birthdate, age, sex, status, marriageDate, noChildren, nationality, acr, address, cityMunicipality, province, telNo, years, offAddress, offCityMunicipality, offProvince, offTelNo, offYears, busAddress, busCityMunicipality, busProvince, busTelNo, busYears, productServiceOffered) VALUES('$amountApplied','$mop','$term','$lastname','$firstname','$middlename','$birthdate','$age','$sex','$status','$marriageDate','$noChildren','$nationality','$acr','$address','$cityMunicipality','$province','$telNo','$years','$offAddress','$offCityMunicipality','$offProvince','$offTelNo','$offYears','$busAddress','$busCityMunicipality','$busProvince','$busTelNo','$busYears','$productServiceOffered')");

$result = $mysqli->query($query);

if ($result) {

    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["error_msg"] = "Application successfully made.";

    echo json_encode($response);
} else {

    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["error_msg"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

and lastly here is my log

> W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value 
>   at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:112) W/System.err:     at
>   org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:163)
>           at org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:176)
>           at info.androidhive.bottomnavigation.fragment.ApplicationFragment.lambda$submitClient$4$ApplicationFragment(ApplicationFragment.java:253)
>           at info.androidhive.bottomnavigation.fragment.-$$Lambda$ApplicationFragment$8jvL3OnFiDofc9nz50lAoSvp9ew.onResponse(Unknown
>   Source:4)
>           at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
>           at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
>           at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)

Comment: If you should get JSON, but get HTML, it's usually because something failed and you got an error page instead, and the error page might actually tell you what went wrong, so look at the `Submission Response:` log entry to see the HTML.

Comment: I just double check the log in debug it says. that it has Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method DB_Connect in line of mysqli_query

Comment: So it's an error on the server, not your code, and whoever is responsible for the server needs to fix it.